# For loop with printf as arguments

Tags: c, for-loop, printf-debugging

I can't understand why the following code outputs `10`.
What I understand is that `!printf("0")` means `!0`, which is `TRUE`. So why doesn't the code print `"Sachin"`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (printf("1"); !printf("0"); printf("2"))
        printf("Sachin");
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
10
```

Comment: Perhaps you need [a `printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to see what it *returns*?

Comment: `printf` returns the number of characters printed. It can print `1`, `10` or nothing at all, depending on after which character it does fail.

Comment: !printf("0") returns false. printf itself returns the number of chars printed if successful. check any c reference for details.

Comment: `!printf("0")` means `!0`... No. Given the result of `printf` it means `!1` which is `FALSE`

Answer (score 8):

let's analyze this side-effect loop statement:

```
for(printf("1"); !printf("0"); printf("2"))
```

- The first statement is executed, always (init condition), yieiding `1`
- Then the condition is tested: `!printf("0")` prints `0`, then since `printf` returns 1 because it just prints 1 character, the negation returns `0` and the loop is never entered because the condition is false right from the start. So neither `2` or `Sachin` are printed.

Of course, this code isn't practical, almost unreadable. So don't ever do things like this (`puts("10");` is a good alternative for instance).

more on the return value of `printf` (that is often ignored):

> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).

(from https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Comment: Meaning no offence sir, this code may not be practical but to me it's experimental which is important to understand the things better. However, I thank you for your assistance. 

Comment: no offence taken. I added that bit in my answer so everyone understands that if you want to print `10` you just do `printf("10");`

Comment: And only write `puts("10");` if you also require a newline.  ;-)

Comment: aaah right I wanted to avoid `printf` when no formatting was needed :)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [man printf](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/printf.3.html) reference on google, you'll see that this function returns the number of written bytes.

Here your condition is `!printf("0")`, in other words : "as long as the return of printf is not existing (or equal 0), do something. But you print the character '0' so printf actually return 1 so your condition is false.

Now WHY it prints 10 :

- The first `printf("1")` prints 1.
- Your condition is tested at least once, so the second `printf("0")` occurs one time (it prints 0)

Comment: good first answer. Small piece of advice: don't tell people to "look on google". Google for them and include the link. It's better.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("1")
```

> prints 1 and it return number of characters which is 1

```
printf("0")
```

> prints 0 and it return number of characters which is 1

**!1 means !(true) = false** so execution will stop and you will see 10 as output.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the assistance.